# MySQL service wont start windows

Tags: mysql, windows

I have a problem with MySQL server on windows, the service won't start. I have removed it with "mysqld --remove" then reinstall with "mysqld --install" but the error still occurs.

[MySQL service Error Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqpwO.png)

Answer (score 3):

you have to check the log file of mysql which is saving all errors. You'll then know what's going on.
The file suffix is .err and you should find it a mysql directory

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I had to use this command to allow the service to work, run command "mysqld --initialize" while in the bin of mysql server. Then start the service with "net start mysql" while in admin cmd

Comment: _WARNING:_ `mysqld --initialize` is useful if the `data` directory empty.